# Processing sketch updates but doesn't draw

Tags: image-processing, processing

So I am trying to write a processing sketch to change the color of a image.

But for some reason it always does things i can't even understand. For example it just won't update the outputed image even when i change the colors of it.

When i check, the colors of the image are changing but it just doesn't change on screen.

Sometimes it also only changes certain parts of the image.

I'd really apreciate somebody taking a look at this.

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```java
PImage img;
PImage image;

void setup() {
  fullScreen();
  img = loadImage("ship.jpg");
  image = img;
  for (int i = 0; i < img.pixels.length; i++) {
    color c = color(img.pixels[i]);
    float re = red(c);
    float gree = green(c);
    float blu = blue(c);
    image.pixels[i] = color(re, gree, blu);
  }
}

void draw() {
  float r = random(255);
  float g = random(255);
  float b = random(255);
  PImage newI = img;

  for (int i = 0; i < newI.pixels.length; i++) {
    float red = red(image.pixels[i]);
    float re = warp(r+red, 0, 255);

    float green = green(image.pixels[i]);
    float gree = warp(g+green, 0, 255);

    float blue = blue(image.pixels[i]);
    float blu = warp(b+blue, 0, 255);

    newI.pixels[i] = color(re, gree, blu);
  }
  image(newI, 0, 0);
  println(red(newI.pixels[0]) + "-" + green(newI.pixels[0]) + "-" + blue(newI.pixels[0]));
}

float warp(float v, float start, float stop) {
  if (v < start) {
    float rest = start-v;
    v = stop-rest;
    v = warp(v, start, stop);
  }
  if (v > stop) {
    float rest = v-stop;
    v = start+rest;
    v = warp(v, start, stop);
  }
  return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need to call `loadPixels()` before you do the modification, and `updatePixels()` after you do the modification.

From [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_updatePixels_.html):

```
PImage myImage;
int halfImage;

void setup() {
  size(100, 100);
  halfImage = width * height/2;
  myImage = loadImage("apples.jpg");
  myImage.loadPixels();
  for (int i = 0; i < halfImage; i++) {
    myImage.pixels[i+halfImage] = myImage.pixels[i];
  }
  myImage.updatePixels();
}

void draw() {
  image(myImage, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I totally forgot about that and I didn't realise it, because for some reason it sometimes drew something. Thank you for pointing that out.